# how can i use RegExp to detecting duplicated specific input in string variables

Tags: regex, string, flutter, dart, string-length

**dart**
**flutter**

i need regular expression to know if a string variable than coming from user inputs contains more than 1 same input

wanted inputs that i want handle it (- _ .)

the wanted input that i won't be repeated more than once is - or . or _

lets say user wrote `Alex.9` .. well it is sound good because he wrote one dot
well i already know how to handle in case there are two dot next to each other like `Alex..9`
with using `contains('..')`, but if those two dots were not next to each other like A.le.x result will be `false`

what i want by no and ok :=

```
Alex.9 => ok
A.le.x => no
Alex-9 => ok
A-le-x9 => no
Alex_9 => ok
Al_e_x9 => no


 // also if there was two or the whole difference  of (- _ .) in the same string. like
 A.le-x => no
 A.le_x => no
 A-l_9 => no
 A.l-x_9 => no
```

**sample of what i mean**

```
final TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
Scaffold(
body: nameController.text.contains(RegExp('Is - or _ or . duplicated?'))?
      Text('yes duplicated') : Text('not duplicated'),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regular expression: `[._-](.*[._-])+`

Comment: thank you so mush .. 72 hors trying to handle this issue .. you just saved me